# React - Wait for state update before useEffect happens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a component (ItemsIndex) that is using a custom hook to fetch data from our API. However the ItemsIndex `useEffect` runs first therefore the DOM is not yet being filled with the elements that could be scrolled into view. How could I wait for the useItems to load first so the DOM renders with the itemTree elements and ids, I recon this would also fix the scrolling issue as it would find the elements by Id.

```js
const ItemsIndex = () => {
    const itemsContext = useContext(ItemsContext);
    const [uploaditemModalOpen, setUploaditemModalOpen] = useState(false);
    const [deleteModalOpen, setDeleteModalOpen] = useState(false);
    const [deleteitem, setDeleteitem] = useState("");

    const { error, loading, items, itemId, setItems } = useItems();

    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
    const resolvedItems = loading ? MOCK_ITEMS : items;

    useEffect(() => {
        // Decode the itemDownload query parameter from the URL
        const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        const itemDownload = params.get("itemDownload");
        if (!itemDownload) return;

        const decodedItemPath = decodeURIComponent(itemDownload);

        try {
            scrollToItem(decodedItemPath); // Doesn't scroll the item into view because can't find the element with id, as its not rendered yet.
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }, []);
```

Use Items hook:

```js
export const useItems = () => {
    const [items, setItems] = useState<ItemTree>({ content: {} });
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const { scope, groupData } = useSelector(state);

    const itemId = scope.ItemId;
    const groupHierarchy = groupData?.path || undefined;

    useEffect(() => {
        const cachedItems = StorageUtils.get(Items_KEY);
        if (cachedItems) {
            setItems(JSON.parse(cachedItems));
            return;
        }
        const retrieveVisibleItems = async () => {
            try {
                setLoading(true);
                const { authItems } = await fetchItems(itemId, groupHierarchy);
                setItems(authItems);
                StorageUtils.set(Items_KEY, JSON.stringify(authItems));
            } catch (err) {
                setError(err);
            } finally {
                setLoading(false);
            }
        };
        retrieveVisibleItems();
    }, [itemId, groupHierarchy]);

    return { error, loading, items, itemId, setItems };
```

Comment: maybe you are looking for `useLayoutEffect`?

Comment: @programandoconro to use on the index component or for the custom hook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All hooks are executed sequentially in the order they are written. So, `useItems` would already being called before `useEffect` in `ItemsIndex`.

Your problem is that `useItems` updates `items` asynchronously by fetching data from server whereas when `useEffect` executes, the `items` are still not fetched.

In `useEffect`, you need to check if `items` are loaded, that is create a dependency on `items`.

```js
const ItemsIndex = () => {
  const { items } = useItems();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (Object.keys(items?.content) === 0) { // condition that items are not loaded
      return;
    }
    scrollToItem(...);
  }, [items]);

  // rest code
};
```

When `items` variable is updated, it will first render DOM and then call this `useEffect`.